# Can't get hello world unit test for Apex REST working

Tags: apex, unit-test, apexrest

I'm in a scratch org and created `SalesRepAPI.apxc` as follows:

```java
@RestResource(urlMapping='/get_sales_rep/*')
global with sharing class SalesRepAPI {
    @HttpGet
    global static Id getSalesRep() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        // grab the caseId from the end of the URL
        //String caseId = request.requestURI.substring(request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        Id returnMe = [SELECT Id FROM User LIMIT 1][0].Id;
        return returnMe;
    }
}
```

And then I also created `SalesRepAPI_TEST.apxc` as follows *(among other things jumping straight to unit-testing because for some reason I can't figure out how to get Workbench to work against a scratch org and I'm too lazy to go around grabbing my session ID, firing up Postman, etc.)*, which has 2 failing tests that I was hoping would pass:

```java
@IsTest
private class SalesRepAPI_TEST {
    @isTest static void testGet() {
        // Set up a test request
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();  
        req.requestUri = '/services/apexrest/get_sales_rep/';// + recordId;
        req.httpMethod = 'GET';
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response= res;
        
        Test.startTest();
        // Call the method to test
        Id salesRepId = SalesRepAPI.getSalesRep();
        Test.stopTest();
        
        // Verify results
        Assert.isNotNull(salesRepId, 'Class ID');
        Assert.areEqual(200, res?.statusCode); // ERROR:  "Assertion Failed: Expected: 200, Actual: null"
        Assert.isNotNull(res?.responseBody?.toString(), 'Response ID'); // ERROR:  "Assertion Failed: Instance expected to be a non null value: Response ID"
    }    
}
```

What am I missing about getting something to actually populate into `res.statusCode`?

---

### Update:

I decided this would have to do for feeling confident I didn't botch getting `SalesRepAPI.getSalesRep()` to take parameters, since at the moment, all branches of `Sales_Rep_Suggester` *(including null parameters)* lead to the same User:

```java
@RestResource(urlMapping='/get_sales_rep/*')
global with sharing class SalesRepAPI {
    @TestVisible private static String unitTestHelperCountry;
    @HttpGet
    global static Id getSalesRep() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        String paramCountry = req.params.get('country');
        unitTestHelperCountry = paramCountry;
        String paramFirstTimeCustomer = req.params.get('firstTimeCustomer');
        Boolean paramBoolFirstTimeCustomer = ( String.isBlank(paramFirstTimeCustomer) ? FALSE : Boolean.valueOf(paramFirstTimeCustomer) );
        Flow.Interview flw = new Flow.Interview.Sales_Rep_Suggester(
            new Map<String, Object>{
                'Country_of_Residence' => paramCountry
                    , 'First_Time_Customer' => paramBoolFirstTimeCustomer
                    }
        );
        flw.start();
        User u = (User) flw.getVariableValue('Sales_Rep_User');
        return u.Id;
    }
}
```

```java
@IsTest
private class SalesRepAPI_TEST {
    @isTest static void testGet() {
        // Set up a test request
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
        req.requestUri = '/services/apexrest/get_sales_rep/';
        req.addParameter('country', 'Japan');
        req.addParameter('firstTimeCustomer', String.valueOf(FALSE));
        req.httpMethod = 'GET';
        RestContext.request = req;
        
        Test.startTest();
        // Call the method to test
        Id salesRepId = SalesRepAPI.getSalesRep();
        Test.stopTest();
        
        // Verify results
        Assert.isNotNull(salesRepId, 'Class ID');
        // Note:  Apex unit tests can't validate the contents of RestResponse-typed objects, so don't bother checking for statusCode 200, a body that matches "salesRepID," etc.
        // This hack is about the closest we can get to using a unit test to make sure that the SalesRepAPI is truly accepting HTTP parameters.
        Assert.areEqual('Japan', SalesRepAPI.unitTestHelperCountry);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of an actual Apex REST call, the RestRequest and RestResponse objects don't automatically update their values. You should not assert the final two conditions, because those values are not live inside of a unit test.

Comment: OK, getting over my laziness w/ Postman it is, then!